# "Daily Pass" as an In-App-Purchase

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

We are currently in preparation for an iPhone app for a local newspaper. In a few weeks the newspaper will be implementing paid premium content on its website alongside free content. It's planned that there will be several ways to purchase this content:

- Single article
- Daily subscription
- Monthly subscription
- Yearly subscription

A registered user should also be allowed to access the same content inside the iPhone app. Now we have several questions regarding this system:

1. Since all content purchased outside of the app needs also to be available as In-App-Purchase do we need to have all 4 subscription methods as In-App (article/daily/monthly/yearly)? Or can we skip some of these? (The single article would cost approx. 20c which is not possible with in app).
2. Is it even possible to have a daily subscription since Apple states that the shortest subscription time is 7 days?
3. Can the daily subscription be solved as a consumable? Is it allowed that a consumable expires after a period of time (i.e. 24h)?

Comment: I've only got some idea of 1 and 2, not sure about 3.

As far as I understand it, you do need all purchase forms. Daily subscriptions are impossible, but you can still deliver the product daily, but they will still be billed for at least a week, so price accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question is, "Talk to a lawyer if you want an answer you can bank on."
The second and third questions, no it's not. However, you can have daily consumables, if you so choose.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do daily subscriptions to iOS apps, as you must choose from one of the following durations ([citation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/CreatingInAppPurchaseProducts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013727-CH3-SW11)):

1. 7 days
2. 1 month
3. 2 months
4. 3 months
5. 6 months
6. 1 year

However, if you offer daily subscriptions via another platform you can always honor the daily subscriptions in your iOS app.